# Extract the $0$-th coefficient from given series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, generating-functions

Let there be a function:
$$F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$$
$$F(x)=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}a_ne^{inx}$$

For some real-valued sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$

> How to extract the zeroth coefficient ($a_0$) ?

I was considering the usage of derivatives in this case, but i didn't figure out how to do this.

Thank you for help.

Comment: **Hint:** What are the integrals $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \exp(i n x) \mathrm{d}x $ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: You should find out about Fourier series.